# Angularjs manual bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

I would like to manually bootstrap my angular app on dom load but Angular doesn't seem to be able to bootstrap my app when i try to wait until dom load

```
 <body>
 <div ng-app="myApp">
  {{1 + 1}}
 </div>
 <script src="angular.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="delay.js"></script>

</body>
```

And here's delay.js

```
window.onload = function(){
console.log('reached 2')
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
}

console.log('reached 1')
```

The above code throws with the following error.

```
reached 1 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify th...<omitted>...0) 
reached 2
```

After looking at various other examples, the bootstrapping seems to work seamlessly when i do it outside the window.onload event like this.

delay.js

```
//this bootstrap works 
angular.module('myApp',[])
console.log('reached 1')
```

Not sure what's happening here, is the module not visible to angular during the onload callback ?

Further even the following in delay.js fails

```
//still fails to bootstrap     
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('reached 2')
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
    })
```

Even the following fails to work

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
console.log('reached 2')
angular.bootstrap(document,[myApp])
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
})
```

OR

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
console.log('reached 2')
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
angular.bootstrap(document,[myApp])
})
```

OR even

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
angular.bootstrap(document.body.children[0],['myApp'])
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
console.log('reached 2')
})
```

Comment: The above error does make sense, as the dom is trying to access myApp,  which is not yet initialized.  And according to the Angular documentation, you need to add  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);

Comment: but that is why i'm trying to bootstrap the app after dom load event,  besides even when i try "angular.bootstrap(document,[myApp])" the bootstrapping fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS bootstraps itself automatically on `DOMContentLoaded`. This event fires as soon as the DOM is ready. That means you don't have to manually bootstrap your app if all you need is the DOM being ready.

The `window.onload` event however waits for all content to be loaded. That includes all scripts, images and other resources.

In case you still want to manually bootstrap on `ready`, this is how you do it:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

`angular.bootstrap` will create the app for you on the element specified. In this case on `document`. This means you don't need to have the `ng-app` directive if you manually bootstrap your app. (Please note that I first incorrectly assumed that you still need it.)

You can not have your module declaration inside your ready callback, because as [stated in the developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap):

> "Notice that angular.bootstrap will not create modules on the fly. You
>   must create any custom modules before you pass them as a parameter."

Here is a corrected fiddle that shows that `ng-app` isn't needed when manually bootstrapping: http://jsfiddle.net/Yxaba/

Comment: hmm.. makes logical sense, but even this doesn't seem to be working. I'll update the edited code with your suggestion

Comment: That's probably because you have your module definition inside your ready callback. See my edit above.

Comment: thanks for the fiddle !
but i'm still trying to understand why i can't initialize my module inside the callback

Comment: also it appears like you don't really have to bootstrap from a handle to the div. It seems to work on the entire DOM as well http://jsfiddle.net/7U87n/2/

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I incorrectly assumed you still need `ng-app` if you manually bootstrap. I have updated my answer to reflect that and have posted a link to why you cannot have your module declaration inside the ready callback as well.

Comment: You can declare your modules inside the ready callback just fine, you just have to declare the modules before calling the bootstrap function.  (e.g. in the same order shown in the developer guide).  I am experimenting with doing this in a window.onload in order to set up angular after Dart stuff has run.